# SQL no results but query

Tags: sql

Even though my query is 'Successful' whenever I execute it, there are no results produced.

```
SELECT  p.*,
        (h.totalCost + e.totalCost + t.totalCost + f.totalCost) as 'Total Package Cost'
FROM package p
  INNER JOIN hotels h ON h.hotelId = p.hotelId
  INNER JOIN excursions e ON e.excursionId = p.excursionId
  INNER JOIN transport t ON t.transportId = p.transportId
  INNER JOIN flight f ON f.flightId = p.flightId
WHERE h.location = 'Spain'
  AND e.location = h.location
  AND t.location = h.location
  AND f.location = h.location
ORDER BY (h.totalCost + e.totalCost + t.totalCost + f.totalCost) ASC
```

Could someone please define the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Since you haven't shown your data, I can only guess that at least one of `hotels`, `excursions`, `transport`, or `flight` doesn't have a `location = 'Spain'`.

Comment: Why double join conditions everywhere, i.e. both location and different id's? BTW, you can do order by 'Total Package Cost'. (Which dbms?, single quotes are for string literals in ANSI SQL...)

Comment: What is the DBMS you are using?

Comment: No, because a successful query with no data returned is the correct and expected result when you issue a query with no matching data.  Therefore, the "problem" is either 1) you've constructed your query in a way that does not match the structure of your tables or 2) there are genuinely no records in the database that JOIN together as specified in your query.  In the first case we need to see the definitions of your tables, in the second we need to see the definitions *and* data for the rows you believe should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

No, we can't define the problem because we can't see your data to know if anything exists to match your query.  However, I can suggest some things to try and trouble-shoot your potential problem.

1. Remove all the where clause to see if you get any results. Sorry if this returns way too much data.
2. Remove all the related tables and add one at a time to see if you get any data. Again, sorry if this returns too much data.
3. Put back the where clause items one by one to see where you may not have any matching data.

You may need to perform some separate queries on each of your joins to understand if the on clauses you are using really work.